# SQL INSERT INTO with SELECT & string

Tags: c#, sql

how to combine below sql?

```
cNamesql = "SELECT ContactName FROM Contact WHERE Contact_ID = '0001'";
sql = "INSERT INTO PurchaseInfo (ContactName) VALUES ('Contact Name "+ cNamesql + "');
```

Exp: ContactName = Andy, contact_ID is '0001'.

So the second sql should looks like

```
INSERT INTO PurchaseInfo (ContactName) VALUES ('Contact Name Andy');
```

How to combine two sql into one sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Insert into ... select ....from ...](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263(v=sql.105).aspx) like this

```
INSERT INTO PurchaseInfo (ContactName)
SELECT 'ContactName ' + ContactName 
FROM Contact WHERE Contact_ID = '0001'
```

Comment: I want the values as "ContactName Andy" instead "Andy"

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need to have a static value for name in columns, i just made a slight modification in @Triv 's answer

```
INSERT INTO PurchaseInfo (ContactName)
SELECT 'ContactName ' + ContactName AS Expr1
FROM Contact WHERE Contact_ID = '0001'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO PurchaseInfo (ContactName) 
VALUES (CONCAT('Contact Name',SELECT ContactName FROM Contact WHERE Contact_ID = '0001'));
```

JUST UPDATING @TriV ANSWER, i AM ALSO NEWBIE GIVE A TRY :)

Comment: not working, error shows Concat is no recognize as a built in function name.

Answer (score 0):

Do this if you are using SQLServer:

```
DECLARE @strContactName varchar(50)
select @strContactName = ContactName  from Contact WHERE Contact_ID = '0001';
INSERT INTO PurchaseInfo (ContactName) VALUES (@strContactName);
```